# Is this a reasonable use of method attributes in python?

Tags: python

I have many different python files, each with many different methods. Each of those methods does some task, and I want to save the results of that task with a filename that describes the outputs and parameters for that method. My current idea is to have, for each method, a dictionary with a return_name:file_name structure, saved as a method attribute, e.g.

```
def addNumbers(number_1, number_2):
    addNumbers.filename_dictionary = {
        "number1": "number1_" + str(number_1) + ".txt",
        "number2": "number2_" + str(number_2) + ".txt"
    }
    final_number = number_1 + number_2
    return final_number
```

The basic motivation for this is that I want to keep all of the information related to that method inside of it, so if I wanted to change the filename it would be easy. One alternative I thought of was to have a similarly named method that just returns the dictionary, but this seemed like a more convenient way to do it.

```
def addNumbers(number_1, number_2):
    added_number = number_1 + number_2
    multiplied_number = number_1 * number_2
    return added_number, multiplied_number

def addNumbersDictionary(number_1, number_2):
    return {
        "added_number": "added" + str(number_1) + "_"+ str(number_2)+".txt",
        "multiplied_number": "multiplied" + str(number_1) + "_"+ str(number_2)+".txt",
    }
```

Some questions: Are there any fundamental flaws to this idea? Are there alternative patterns that would solve this problem in a more standard way? Is the actual problem poorly defined or doesn't make sense?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you need a dictionary and how do you intend to use it?

Comment: When I want to save the outputs of the method, I want to get the filenames as defined in the dictionary. So, I would call addNumbers.filename_dictionary when I want the filenames to save added_number and multiplied_number.

Comment: Note that those are functions, not methods (methods belong to a class).

Comment: Oh, thank you for the distinction - I wasn't aware of this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's forget about your example code and just stick with your main problem statement (slightly rephrased):

> I have many different python files, each with many different functions. I want to save results of those functions with a filename that describes the outputs and parameters.

Out of curiousity, may I ask why "with a filename" ?

Anyway: you want to somehow "save" the parameters and related result for some functions calls. The simple way to do this in Python is to use a function decorator. Here's a quick&dirty example, using a global dict to save the data you're interested in:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from functools import wraps
saved_data = defaultdict(list)

def save(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        saved_data[func.__name__].append({"args": args, "kwargs": kwargs, "result": result})
        return result

    return wrapper 


@save
def add_nums(num1, num2):
   return num1 + num2


add_nums(1, 2)
add_nums(3, 4)
add_nums(num2=2, num1=1)

print(saved_data)
```

Now you have collected your data, you can do whatever you want with them.

This can be vastly improved of course (ie avoiding the global `saved_data`, using `inspect.getargspecs(func)` to have a more uniform representation of the saved arguments etc, but this should at least get you started.

NB: if you really want "filenames describing the outputs and parameters", you can either rewrite the decorator so that it saves those "filenames" instead of the actual values, or generate those filenames afterward from the collected values.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about decorators before this. Filenames was simply my use-case for the pattern, you're correct that I can rewrite the decorator or generate them afterwards.

Comment: Hi bruno, what is the purpose of @wraps(func) in this example code? I tried removing it, and nothing about the output changed.

Comment: @eygrr it makes `save()` a well-behaved decorator - preserving the decorated function's name and docstring - as documented here https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps